# Firebase total user count (IOS)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

I'm exploring methods to obtain the total user count for my iOS mobile app using Firebase. Although a similar question was asked nearly eight years ago, I believe there might be updated solutions available now.
However, I'm uncertain about where to start. My development stack consists solely of Firebase, Swift, and SwiftUI, utilizing cloud firestore.

Comment: Nothing has changed.  There is no client API for getting a user count, so you have to manage it yourself. Use the advice in the duplicate.  If you want to know if something changes, keep looking for new answers on that duplicate.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your response. However, it seems that the user asking received information related to a web app utilizing the Firebase Admin SDK. If I am building this app entirely in Swift/SwiftUI with Firebase, how can I integrate the Firebase Admin SDK to achieve the total count of users?

Comment: The asker tagged their question with angular, which is frontend and can't use the Admin SDK.  Look at the answers more carefully.  You can build a backend (using Cloud Functions) and invoke it from your app.  You will definitely need a backend for this.  Either that, or count records that you create in some database managed by your app.

Comment: @DougStevenson Understood, one more question: I'm relatively new to this, but I thought Firebase was considered a backend. Are these cloud functions just extending Firebase in a sense? Could you direct me to possible resources to understand the distinction between Firebase as a backend and additional backend solutions like cloud functions?

Comment: The Admin SDK isn’t necessarily a web app. You just need VSCode.

Comment: Why don't you start with the documentation and tutorials for Cloud Functions?